# Generate a pdf from opengles context in iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es, pdf-generation

Hi am a noob at PDF generation and currently am displaying a 3d bar charts in my application in glview which is in side a uiview. Now i want to generate a PDF document from the uiview which contains a text view and a glview. Am able to generate a PDF from text but where as GL View am unable to proceed.even i tried for a possibility over the net but unable to get any info regarding this.Can someone help me by providing the solution whether this can be possible or not.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can ask any UIView to give you an image (which might be a start) via something like:

```
- (UIImage *) imageRepresentation {
    // render myself (or more correctly, my layer) to an image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(context, false);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, false);

    [self drawLayer:self.layer inContext:context];
    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

After that, you might be able to get a PDF representation of it, or investigate calls like `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL` to construct one yourself from the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoreGraphic's PDF-APIs to creating and drawing to a PDF.

See [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101) for more details.